UnityのARkitを使って瞼の動きを検知したい
UnityでApple ARKit XR Plugin 5.0.7を使用し、瞼の動きを検知したいです。
ARFaceAnchor上のパラメータでは係数が変化しているのですが、その係数を取得することができません。
どなたか、アドバイスお願いいたします。
